# Continue parts of nested loop if condition of one loop is not met at exactly the beginning

Tags: java, bukkit

I have exactly 3-level nested loop. If an input is exactly 0, the execution of other for loops should continue so normal nested loop won't work
I tried thinking of a workaround but i have no idea how would i make it work. Any kind of solution is welcome

I have 3 inputs that are some kind of "multipliers". If the value is 0, the execution should still continue.

Example:

```
int coni=2, conj=-2, conk=0;
//intermediate values that tell should it be negative or positive
//calculated from the beginning values, but ill get rid of the code
int ti=1,tj=-1,tk=0;

for(int i=0;i<(int)Math.abs(coni);i++){
    for(int j=0;i<(int)Math.abs(conj);j++){
        for(int k=0;i<(int)Math.abs(conk);k++){
            //will never get executed
            function(i*ti,j*tj,k*tk);
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to happen:

```
function(0,0,0);
function(0,-1,0);
function(1,0,0);
function(1,-1,0);
```

Comment: what about `<=` inside the for loops instead of `<` ?

Comment: @papaya Implementation is kind of complicated, so that won't work in my case. This is used for 3d rendering the result and if its 0 it should omit the dimension completely and thats the part that breaks nested loop. If i set it to <= 1 would mean its gonna print twice but i want 1 for 1, nothing for 0

Comment: What is the expected function call for input `coni, conj and conk =0` ?

Comment: It should just be function(0,0,0);

Comment: It does that when you set `<=` in all the nested loop conditions. Please provide an example where it doesnt match your expectations

Comment: Now that i have actually tried it it looks like it works exactly as i want it to, but only half of the program works properly so i believe the problem must have been somewhere else all the time and messed up my result. I tried the <= before already but i make rapid changes in code and might have forgotten to just try it again. Sorry!

Comment: Updated with an answer! Cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `<=` instead of `<` in your `for loop` will help you achieve what you want.

```
for(int i=0;i<=(int)Math.abs(coni);i++){
    for(int j=0;i<=(int)Math.abs(conj);j++){
        for(int k=0;i<=(int)Math.abs(conk);k++){
            //will never get executed
            function(i*ti,j*tj,k*tk);
        }
    }
}
```

This will execute

```
function(0,0,0)
```